# Combining results from two classes

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-6

In this method below I am working out a products code(**StockItem**):

```
    var qisg = new QuoteItemSectionGroup
    {
        SectionGroup = db.SectionGroups.Where(x => x.Name == "Longitudinals" && x.Section == TruckSection.Floor).First(),
        StockItem = quoteItem.BodyType.Longitudinal, <<--------
        Quantity = 2,
        Length = globals.FloorCalculatedLength
    };
```

I have two classes called: **BodyType** & **Chassis**. Both has a column called **Longitudinal**.

In my method above I have worked out the **BodyType.Longitudinal** and = it to my **StockItem**.

```
StockItem = quoteItem.BodyType.Longitudinal,
```

The problem is that I have to set the second class **Chassis.Longitudinal** = to my **StockItem** aswell at the same time.

```
StockItem = quoteItem.Chassis.Longitudinal,
```

Example:

```
StockItem = quoteItem.BodyType.Longitudinal + quoteItem.Chassis.Longitudinal,
```

Is there a way to do this? I am just showing the example, because I have no idea how to do this.

EDIT: This is where I set the code for each **StockItem**

**BodyType**

```
context.BodyTypes.AddOrUpdate<BodyType>(x => x.Name,
    new BodyType { Name = "Corrugated", isFlatDeck = false, LongitudinalId = context.StockItems.Where(x => x.StockCode == "SCH105").First().Id });
```

**Chassis**

```
context.Chassis.AddOrUpdate<Chassis>(x => x.Name,
    new Chassis { Name = "DAIHATSU DELTA V116", LongitudinalId = context.StockItems.Where(x => x.StockCode == "SCH100").First().Id });
```

Comment: I don't get what are you trying two achieve? Two `StockItems` in one `QuoteItemSectionGroup` with different `Longitudinal ` or just sum of them? Added: Probably you need `List<StockItem>` instead of just `StockItem`

Comment: @szer - Only one `StockItem` in one `QuoteItemSectionGroup`. I've posted an EDIT on where I set the Longitudinal for each class. I need the application to select **a** Longitudinal from one of the two classes

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand what you are trying to achieve, can't be done without changing the `QuoteItemSectionGroup` class.

You should modify the `StockItem` into something like may be dictionary.

```
StockItem<string, string>;  // You can decide on the data type.
```

And then fill data somewhat like this.

```
    var qisg = new QuoteItemSectionGroup
        {
            SectionGroup = db.SectionGroups.Where(x => x.Name == "Longitudinals" && x.Section == TruckSection.Floor).First(),
            StockItem.Add('BodyType.Longitudinal',quoteItem.BodyType.Longitudinal);
            StockItem.Add('Chassis.Longitudinal',quoteItem.Chassis.Longitudinal); <<--------
            Quantity = 2,
            Length = globals.FloorCalculatedLength
        };
```